# Laravel/Jetstream Change admin route and vie after login success

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I'm using Laravel + jetstream + inertia. I trying to use change home route and laravel `view()` instead of `Inertia::render()` but maybe there is something wrong. Instead redirect to `/admin` my application stays at `http://localhost/login` and shows a popup with the content of the admin page as below image

[image: Screen]

Comment: use console to see network response and write here

Answer (score 0):

If you have a page that doesn't need a corresponding controller method,like an FAQ or about page, you can route directly to a component.

```
Route::inertia('/home', 'HomeComponent');
```